# Remove part of json content

Tags: javascript, json, fs

I want my json-file to be edited when the given time/date is in the past. I've tried *delete termine[0]* but this does not delete the part of the file.

*My json-file*

```
    [{
    "datum": "2020-10-10T10:00:00",
    "event": "..."
    },
    {
    "datum": "2021-10-10T10:00:00",
    "event": "..."
    },...
    ]
```

*My Code*

```
let termine = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync("/home/pi/NeonBot/termine.json", "utf8"))

var now = new Date();
var date = termine[0].datum
    date = new Date(date)

do {
    delete termine[0]
    console.log(`Deleted Event`)
} while (date < now)
```

Comment: You want the file itself to be modified? Then you need to write back to the file. Modifying the object you get back from reading and parsing the file will not modify the underlying file.

Comment: @InstanceHunter That is the problem. I could use fs.writeFile() but don't know how to delete only a part of that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have an infinite loop, because you never update `date` in the loop.

You should also check the condition before deleting, not after.

```
while (new Date(termine[0].datum_) < now) {
    delete termine[0];
    console.log("Deleted Event");
}
```

Instead of deleting one element at a time, find the index of the first element to keep, then remove all the ones before it with `splice`.

```
let index = termine.findIndex(event => new Date(event.datum) >= now);
if (index > 0) {
    termine.splice(0, index);
}

fs.writeFileSync("/home/pi/NeonBot/termine.json", JSON.stringify(termine), "utf8");
```

Comment: But the file is still not edited. Your answer only edited the array.

Comment: Just write it back to the file, I added that to the answer.